# Azure. ApplicationInsights. Inexplicable error messge in AI log

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-performancecounters

I have setup AppllicationInsights resource in Azure portal. There are 2 services writing to it: windows service on premise and service fabric service running on a local service fabric cluster. I am using *TelemetryClient* object in both services to send data to the Azure ApplicationInsights resource. It looks like I am getting all messages I wanted, but there are some messages origin of which I don't understand. Here is example of the strange message:

> AI: Error collecting 6 of the configured performance counters. Please
>   check the configuration. Counter \ASP.NET
>   Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec: Failed to perform the
>   first read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists.
>   Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests/Sec, instance
>   SFAIUsingSrv.exe 
>   Counter .NET CLR Exceptions(??APP_CLR_PROC??)# of
>   Exceps Thrown / sec: Failed to perform the first read for performance
>   counter. Please make sure it exists. Category: .NET CLR Exceptions,
>   counter: # of Exceps Thrown / sec, instance  
>   Counter \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Request Execution Time: Failed to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it
>   exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Request Execution
>   Time, instance SFAIUsingSrv.exe 
> .Counter \ASP.NET
>   Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests In Application Queue: Failed
>   to perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it
>   exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests In
>   Application Queue, instance SFAIUsingSrv.exe 
>   Counter \Process(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Handle Count: Failed to perform the first
>   read for performance counter. Please make sure it exists. Category:
>   Process, counter: Handle Count, instance SFAIUsingSrv.exe 
>  Counter
>   \ASP.NET Applications(??APP_W3SVC_PROC??)\Requests/Sec: Failed to
>   perform the first read for performance counter. Please make sure it
>   exists. Category: ASP.NET Applications, counter: Requests/Sec,
>   instance SFAIUsingSrv.exe

Here is my ApplicationInsights.config for service fabric service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
  <InstrumentationKey>some instrumentation key</InstrumentationKey>
  <TelemetryInitializers>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureWebAppRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
    </TelemetryInitializers>
    <TelemetryModules>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
            <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
                <!-- 
        Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers. 
        This is only applicable if Profiler is installed via either StatusMonitor or Azure Extension.
        Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
        NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
        -->
                <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
                <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
                <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
                <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
                <Add>localhost</Add>
                <Add>127.0.0.1</Add>
            </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
     <!--      
      The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
        ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
        ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker   process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
        ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
-->
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
            <!--</Add>
    <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.FirstChanceExceptionStatisticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
-->
        </Add>
    </TelemetryModules>
    <TelemetryProcessors>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
            <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
            <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
        </Add>
        <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
            <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
            <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
        </Add>
    </TelemetryProcessors>
    <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel"/>
<!-- 
    Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840

    Note: If not present, please add <InstrumentationKey>Your Key</InstrumentationKey> to the top of this file.
  -->
</ApplicationInsights>
```

> Could anybody help me understand why I am getting those messages?

**EDIT:**
It was my services(windows service and service fabric service) which has been producing those messages. And both those services has been running on my development box. So it was quite confusing to see those messages, related to the web apps, when there are no any web apps being used. But then I commented out PerformanceCounterCollector section in ApplicationInsights.config file messages are no longer being produced, if I will find a way to deal with those messages in a more friendly manner I will update my question.

**EDIT2:**
Those messages is showing up only when services are starting.

**EDIT3:** Here are all nugget packages install for the service fabric service:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it is trying to track metrics from w3Svc which is typically the executable/process responsible for brokering web traffic on IIS. If the service you've implemented doesn't use that process AI will run into trouble tracking those metrics. My guess is that the Windows Service and Service Fabric might not expose that process. It might be safe to ignore...EDIT: You can see the 'APP_W3SVC_PROC' in the config that it's looking for.

Comment: @Porschiey Well, it's services, not web app, which produced those messages. I've removed counters collection all together to remedy the situation for now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if it is a Azure Web App, only a subset of the perfcounters are exposed by Azure, they are *somewhat* documented here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/develop/Src/PerformanceCollector/Shared/Implementation/WebAppPerformanceCollector/CounterFactory.cs

If you're controlling the server, you need to make sure that whatever user is running that IIS website / app pool is a member of `Performance Monitor Users` group so that it can read the perf counters.

These messages are coming out from the default configuration of the PerfCounterCollector package, which is included by the WindowsServer package, which you can see here at the [github source for the perf counter collector](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/2a681f5399a6aaee554fa2d93a1d6447a8402fe1/Src/PerformanceCollector/Shared/PerformanceCollectorModule.cs#L156)

if you aren't using performance collector stuff at all and just want that to all go away, you can remove the entire

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
...stuff about perf counters here...
</Add>
```

section and Application Insights will stop trying to collect perf counters entirely.

Comment: Thank u for the insight! I was able to get rid of messages, but I still quite perplexed why I was seeing them in first place? Especially those related to the web app, when there is no any web app being used...

Comment: your project is apparently configured to use the Web version of application insights, so it assumes that there is a web app being used, and so it tries to collect things you would want.

Comment: Oh... I see. When AI resource is being created its type has been set to ASP.NET. It should have been, probably, set to "General" to reflect reality of its usage better.

Comment: the type displayed in the portal really only changes some behaviors in the portal itself, of what kinds of things are displayed in the overview blades.  What gets sent is entirely up to the sdk and configuration you are using locally.  (you can make a "general" app and send data with the web sdk, you could create the type as "python" and send data to it from node, etc)  Many apps have many different things sending data to the same resource (like web and javascript and node all going to the same place)

Comment: Well, problem was not with what we send to AI, but what AI sends by default.  If you look at ApplicatinInsight.config I've provided there is nothing, that said "web app telemetry need to be collected"(at least to me), that's why I've been struggling to understand why I am getting issues with "out-of-the-box" performance counters.

Comment: did you install applicationinsights.web nuget package?  or just the core sdk nuget package?  because these autocollections are set up here: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-server/blob/2a681f5399a6aaee554fa2d93a1d6447a8402fe1/Src/PerformanceCollector/Shared/PerformanceCollectorModule.cs#L156 which is inside the `web` specific application insights package.  hence why, by default, the *web* package is trying out of the box to record *web* specific perf counters.

Comment: Please take look at my EDIT3. I've put there list of all nugget packages I have for the project. There is no  applicationinsights.web nugget package there. There 2 images, because I could not fit all packages in one page. And there is nothing in between, I swear!:)Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: it looks like they're coming from the server package, which generally is included by the web package.  it assumes you want to collect web stuff by default.  if you don't, you'll have to live with + ignore the error messages, or remove the perf counter collector from the default setup.

Comment: @JohnGardne: I have installed `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web` and still have this issue. I'm using Cloud service (classic) on Azure